# Can't match SQLite Row ID with ListView position when trying to delete an item from the table/list

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

This question has been asked before but none of the implementations helped me so far.

I'm building a to do app and I'm displaying my items in a listview, using SQLite for persistence.  I'm able to dynamically add items to my listview and successfully store them in my database, but I'm not able to delete them from the screen or the table.  I know the reason why.  My SQLite Row ID does not match my ListView.  But the other problem is that I should still be able to delete items off my screen and my table with positions that does match the SQLite Row ID (For example, my 3rd To Do in the list) but I'm not able to delete anything.

This is my method that is supposed to delete items from the database:

```
public boolean itemDeleteFromDatabase(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        boolean databaseDelete = database.delete(TABLE_NAME, TO_DO + "=?" + id, null) > 0;
        listItems.setAdapter(adapter);
        return databaseDelete;
    }
```

And I'm calling this method from my `OnItemLongClick` method, passing in the ListView position as the parameter:

```
listItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View item, int position, long id) {
                toDoItems.remove(position);
                itemDeleteFromDatabase(id);
                MainActivity.this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

This is the stacktrace.  The problem with this is that it only addresses 1 problem in the code:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: ca.ozbek.preworktodoapp, PID: 2105
                                                                       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: variable number must be between ?1 and ?999 (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM student WHERE todo=?0
```

**Adding Source Code per request**

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private final int REQUEST_CODE = 10;
    ArrayList <String> toDoItems = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView listItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewItems);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, toDoItems);
        listItems.setAdapter(adapter);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        getToDos();

        listItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View item, int position, long id) {
                toDoItems.remove(position);
                itemDeleteFromDatabase(id + 1);
                MainActivity.this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
        });

        listItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View item, int pos, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditItemActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("item", toDoItems.get(pos));
                intent.putExtra("itemPos", String.valueOf(pos));
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            String item = data.getStringExtra("item");
            int itemPosition = Integer.parseInt(data.getStringExtra("itemPos"));
            toDoItems.add(itemPosition, item);
            toDoItems.remove(itemPosition + 1);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public void addItem(View v) {
        EditText newItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemInputEditText);

        if (newItem.getText().length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You need to enter a to do.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            String item = newItem.getText().toString();
            databaseHelper.insertData(item);
            adapter.add(item);
            newItem.setText("");
        }
    }

    public  void getToDos(){
        SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from student",null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("todo"));
                adapter.add(name);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean itemDeleteFromDatabase(Long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        boolean databaseDelete = database.delete(TABLE_NAME, TO_DO + "=?", new String[]{Long.toString(id)}) > 0;
        listItems.setAdapter(adapter);
        return databaseDelete;
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "todo.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student";
    public static final String ID = "id";
    public static final String TO_DO = "todo";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String CREATE_TO_DO_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
                + TABLE_NAME
                + "("
                + ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + TO_DO
                + " TEXT"
                + ")";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TO_DO_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String todo) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(TO_DO, todo);
        long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getListContents() {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is basically saying that you haven't provided an argument to match the placement **`?`**. i.e.

```
boolean databaseDelete = database.delete(TABLE_NAME, TO_DO + "=?" + id, null) > 0;
```

Is effectively saying `DELETE FROM table WHERE TO_DO =unobtainablevale 10`

*10 being a made-up id for demonstration*

You could change it to

```
boolean databaseDelete = database.delete(TABLE_NAME, TO_DO + "=" + id, null) > 0;
```

or to

```
boolean databaseDelete = database.delete(TABLE_NAME, TO_DO + "=?", new String[]{Long.toString(id)}) > 0;
```

The latter probably being considered the better.

P.S. not tested so the odd typo might exist.

### Solution 1 using a SimpleCursorAdapter as opposed to an ArrayAdpater

1) in DatabaseHelper change `public static final String ID = "id";` to be `public static final String ID = "_id";` (i.e add the underscore, suggest do this irrespective of method used but NEEDED for CursorAdapter)

#### Note! This will require the existing database to be deleted. Use Settings/Apps, select App and then clear data or uninstall app.

2) add the lines indicated with <<<<< to MainActivity (preparing to use Cursor Adapter, ps will leave the ArrayAdapter stuff generally asis but have to remove some)

```
ArrayList<String> toDoItems = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
SimpleCursorAdapter altadapter;     //<<<<<<<<<
Cursor itemlistcursor;              //<<<<<<<<<
ListView listItems;
```

3) Add  override for `onDestroy` method (not required but cleans up cursor) :-

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    itemlistcursor.close();
}
```

4) Add altertantive method e.g. `getItemListAsCursor` to get data:-

```
public void getItemListAsCursor() {
    SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    itemlistcursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

*Note! uses `query` method instead of `rawQuery` but equates to `SELECT * FROM student;`*

5) Change itemDeleteFromDatabase to use ID column not the TODO column (didn't spot this before) and comment out lines as per the code below:-

```
public boolean itemDeleteFromDatabase(Long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    boolean databaseDelete = database.delete(TABLE_NAME, ID + "=?", new String[]{Long.toString(id)}) > 0;
    //listItems.setAdapter(adapter);
    return databaseDelete;
}
```

6) Comment out the lines as below (get rid of using ArrayAdapater) :-

```
    listItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewItems);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, toDoItems);
    //listItems.setAdapter(adapter);
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    //getToDos();
```

7) Change onItemLongClickListener as below

```
    listItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View item, int position, long id) {
            //toDoItems.remove(position);
            itemDeleteFromDatabase(id);         //<<<<<<
            getItemListAsCursor();              //<<<<<<
            //MainActivity.this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            altadapter.swapCursor(itemlistcursor);  //<<<<<<
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Note! could keep `notifyDatasetChanged` (I just prefer `swapCursor`);

8) Finally add the following just after the commented out `//getToDos` line :-

```
    getItemListAsCursor();
    altadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            itemlistcursor,
            new String[]{ TO_DO},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
            0);
    listItems.setAdapter(altadapter);
```

### Solution 2 using ArrayAdpater

1) Add the complimentary Array for the ID (as per the //<<<<<< line):-

```
    ArrayList <String> toDoItems = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Long> toDoItemsID = new ArrayList<>(); //<<<<<<
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView listItems;
```

2) Change insertData method in DatabaseHelper to return the id by replacing the method with :-

```
public long insertData(String todo) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(TO_DO, todo);
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}
```

3) Change getToDos method to store id into the compliementary array (//<<<<< ):-

```
public  void getToDos(){
    SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from student",null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TO_DO));
            adapter.add(name);
            toDoItemsID.add(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID))); //<<<<<<
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Note! I have also replaced `"todo"` with `TO_DO`

4) Change addItem method to also store id

```
public void addItem(View v) {
    EditText newItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemInputEditText);

    if (newItem.getText().length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You need to enter a to do.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        String item = newItem.getText().toString();
        //databaseHelper.insertData(item);                  //OLD
        toDoItemsID.add(databaseHelper.insertData(item));   //<<<<<<<
        adapter.add(item);
        newItem.setText("");
    }
}
```

Note! I don't like this at all I can envisage issue with keeping toDoItemsID in sync, plus this does currently cater for a not inserted (easy to do as return from insertData should be > 0).

5) Finally the onItemLongClickListener changes :-

```
    listItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View item, int position, long id) {
            itemDeleteFromDatabase(toDoItemsID.get(position)); //<<<<<<
            toDoItems.remove(position);
            toDoItemsID.remove(position);  //<<<<<<
            //itemDeleteFromDatabase(id + 1); // REMOVE
            MainActivity.this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I've tested the above, but may have inadvertently missed something when copying.

Comment: Are you using  a Cursor adapter as opposed to ArrayAdpater?

Comment: Then id will be position if I recall correctly. id will only be id if using cursor adapter. You could create a complimentary array to hold id when building array.

Comment: Correct see previous comment.

Comment: Yes add adapter code and databasehelper code to the question. Will try to show options e.g. usie cursor adapter and complimentary array.

Comment: That's Ok worjking on it now.

Comment: @OnurOzbek will look at that, probably missed a change I made but I suspect that it's because I ignored adding I just inserted some testing rows rather than try to get the add stuff working.

Comment: yep addItem would need to have `getItemListAsCursor();        
            altadapter.swapCursor(itemlistcursor); ` after insertData, instead of `adapter.add(item);`

Comment: @OnurOzbek, if using cursor as opposed to array then you would work with the id not the position.